# Trying to understand JQuery/Ajax Get/POST calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Correct me if I'm wrong but it was my understanding that a POST was to be used if I was changing data, and a GET was to be used if I want to retrieve data.

Based on that assumption.

I have (MVC5) app.

My JavaScript

```
function MyLoadData(myValue) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/GetMyData',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ "MyValue": myValue}),
        success: function (data) {
             // Do Stuff
        }                    
    });
```

and my controller.

```
public JsonResult GetMyData(string myValue)
        {  // Do Stuff }
```

This only works if I set the method: 'POST', if I set it to 'GET' it will still make the server call but not pass the myValue to the controller.

Also of note there is no data annotation on the GetMyData method.

In this scenario shouldn't I be using GET to get my data from the controller?

UPDATED based on comments:

```
function MyLoadData(myValue) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/GetMyData',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "MyValue": myValue},
        success: function (data) {
             // Do Stuff
        }                    
    });
```

Comment: Use your browser tools to see the actual request (and url with parameters) that is being sent. Try not `stringify`ing the data when you do a GET request.

Comment: Why are you setting contentType to 'application/json'?  This is the content type of the data you are sending. The default application/x-www-form-urlencoded is probably fine for your purposes. Ie. just leave that line out.  Otherwise - what happens if you call your controller directly from the browser with a query string ?MyValue=abc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `POST` and `GET` methods can pass the myValue to the controller.

- GET - Requests data from a specified resource
- POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

**GET** is basically used for just getting (retrieving) some data from the server. Note: The GET method may return cached data.

**POST** can also be used to get some data from the server. However, the POST method NEVER caches data, and is often used to send data along with the request.

Comment: I cleaned up my call see above.  However I still have to use the POST for this method to work.  I'll have to read up on Fiddlr for I'm not sure how to test the actual request.  However I can verify on the server side that myValue is being passed to the controller, however the JSON data is not getting passed back to the client. (ie. it never hits my done or success methods).  Only when I set the method to POST will it work.

Comment: AH!  I forgot to add AllowGet in the controller....
return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Nice try. Bien joué !

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between a `GET` and a `POST` is that the `POST` will also submit the form data. In your example, you can use a GET by appending `?MyValue=<myValue>` to your URL and WebAPI will assign the value to the Action's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the GET request needs to work then use this code block:

```
function MyLoadData(myValue) {
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/Home/GetMyData?myValue=test',
    success: function (data) {
         // Do Stuff
    }                    
});
```

Basically, you can use GET or POST to get the data. but in GET, the data is passed through query string. In POST it can be passed both through query string as well as body.

One real world scenario when to use POST-Suppose your method expects Customer parameter and you need to send Customer object as parameter, then you can send the json representation of Customer object through body.but its not possible through GET.

One more reason is security,if you use GET, your method can be called through browser.but if you use POST, the method can't be directly called.

These were the important difference.For more differences see this link - http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET_(HTTP)_vs_POST_(HTTP)